# jupiter notebook and editors

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

While working with ipython I used to edit an object with:

```
ed my_obj
```

And the editor opened the code defining the class of the object. I cannot find how to do the same thing in a jupyter notebook. Is it any possible?

Answer (score 0):

The magic command %ed and %edit won't work in jupyter notebook.

I'm not quite sure why exactly jupyter doesn't support this edition, but probably because it can't know exactly when the user finished editing the file and the edited data should back to the cell.

If you want to edit the content of a **string** in a cell, you can use the following command:

```
a = 'jupyter'
get_ipython().set_next_input(a)
```

You can also use the `%%writefile` to save the content of the cell into a file and edit it outside jupyter.

```
%%writefile test.txt
[1, 2, 3]
```

And also use `%load` to bring the content to the cell:

```
%load test.txt
```